# Como mostrar intervalo de horários disponíveis do dia com base em intervalos marcados da tabela de compromissos no POSTGRES?

Tags: postgresql

Preciso mostrar todos os intervalos de horários disponíveis do dia que ainda não tenham compromissos marcados. Assim, pode-se escolher o horário ainda disponível para marcar. Já consegui fazer detecção de compromissos que se sobrepõem usando OVERLAP na hora de cadastrar um novo compromisso. Porém, não consegui mostrar os intervalos do dia em que ainda não tenho compromisso marcado e usando o OVERLAP, só consigo comparar se o intervalo de horário inserido se sobrepõe a outros.

Minha tabela:

```
CREATE TABLE compromisso
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  data_compromisso date,
  descricao_compromisso varchar(100),
  hora_inicio time without time zone,
  hora_fim time without time zone
)
```

Quero mostrar os horários do dia ainda vagos.

Comment: Como se monta esta tabela ? Qual a regra do intervalo ?

Comment: Defina precisamente o que você chama de "horários disponíveis" bem como "hora inicio do compromisso", pode ser qualquer instante ou tem alguma regra do tipo, é fixa a cada meia hora ou a cada 1 hora? Ou o início e fim podem ser quaisquer e os horários disponíveis são os intervalos entre o fim e início dos compromissos?

Comment: vc precisa definir uma duração padrão de um compromisso, para dizer quais outros estão disponíveis

Comment: Caso cada compromisso tenha duração fixa e inícios predeterminados (por ex. a cada 1 hora das 8:00 às 17:00) você pode utilizar a função `generate_series` para gerar todos os inícios possíveis e verificar os horários vagos, por ex. através de um `LEFT OUTER JOIN` do resultado da função com sua tabela `compromisso` na qual `compromisso.hora_inicio` seja `NULL`.

Comment: Bom dia, pessoal! Primeiramente, gostaria de agradecer a prontidão e gemntileza com que responderam. Acredito que o que vou dizer responderá à todos, bom, vamos lá! "Horários disponíveis"  são todos os horários do dia, ou seja, 12 horas, de 08:00 A.M até 20:00 P.M. E o INTERVALO DE DURAÇÃO é definido pelo usuário ao preencher os dados, sendo que, o horário  de início e dado por "hora_inicio" e o de fim por "hora_fim".

Comment: DEtalhe importante, como essa é a estrutura de uma tabela do postgres, os dados só serão guardados, ou seja, uma linha de registro será gerada, quando for inserido um compromisso com as informações pedidas. Porém, previamente, eu não possuo os dados dos intervalos que não tem compromisso durante o dia. Logo, teria que fazer uma DEDUÇÃO dos horários possíveis no dia menos os que já tenho REGISTRADOS, os quais não podem aparecer mais como horários vagos pois já HÁ um registro, compromisso, marcado para este horário.

Comment: Entenderam o problema, dá para criar uma FUNCTION verificando se no intervalo de 12 horas, 08:00 A.M às 20:00 P.M, existe horários vagos, ou seja, que não haja compromissos marcados ainda, e se houver retornar os horários vagos para que eu possa mostrar ao cliente para que ele escolha e agende seu compromisso?